# Remove some of the X axis labels in ggplot bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I have the following code for a stacked bar graph for the period 1970-2020, which is the X-axis label.
The graph is generated from a dataframe with 3 columns and 51 rows representing various years.

```
Year     Active     New
1970     1          1
......
2020     268        60
```

[image]

```
df %>%
    mutate(Old = Active - New) %>%
    select(-Active) %>%
    pivot_longer(-Year, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Count") %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = Year, y = Count, fill = forcats::fct_rev(Type)))+
    ggtitle("example graph")+
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Cases",
                        breaks=c("Old", "New"),
                        labels=c("Ongoing", "New"))
```

As my X-axis is not readable, I would like to remove most of the Years in the X-axis, and keep eg. 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2020 - at their corresponding positions. I'm not sure that `scale_x_discrete` can do this?

Comment: Why not convert year to a numeric variable? Then the breaks will automatically get pretty breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer in this specific case is to convert `Year` to a numeric variable, which will make the breaks pretty by default.

This sample data allows us to run your code and reproduce your issue:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(Year = factor(1970:2020),
                 Active = cumsum(rnorm(51, 4, 2)),
                 New = cumsum(rnorm(51, 1, 1)))
```

Using your exact plotting code produces a similar plot with unreadable axis labels:

```r
df %>%
    mutate(Old = Active - New) %>%
    select(-Active) %>%
    pivot_longer(-Year, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Count") %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = Year, y = Count, fill = forcats::fct_rev(Type)))+
    ggtitle("example graph")+
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Cases",
                        breaks=c("Old", "New"),
                        labels=c("Ongoing", "New"))
```

[image]

But if we simply convert `Year` to numeric values, we get the same plot with pretty breaks:

```r
df %>%
    mutate(Old = Active - New) %>%
    select(-Active) %>%
    pivot_longer(-Year, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Count") %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(Year)), y = Count, 
                 fill = forcats::fct_rev(Type)))+
    ggtitle("example graph")+
    xlab("Year") +
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Cases",
                        breaks=c("Old", "New"),
                        labels=c("Ongoing", "New"))
```

[image]

If for whatever reason it *needs* to be a factor, you can leave specific years blank using a labeling function.

```r
df %>%
    mutate(Old = Active - New) %>%
    select(-Active) %>%
    pivot_longer(-Year, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Count") %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = Year, y = Count, fill = forcats::fct_rev(Type)))+
    ggtitle("example graph")+
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Cases",
                        breaks=c("Old", "New"),
                        labels=c("Ongoing", "New")) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) ifelse(as.numeric(x) %% 10, "", x)) +
    theme(axis.ticks.length.x = unit(0, "mm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I didn't realise the solution to this is so simple...